# mysql data masking

Tags: mysql, security, anonymous, sanitize, data-masking

Hi
I'd like to a take a production database and use it in a private, development environment.  But, I'd like to anonymize the data.

I've been searching for an hour, but everything I find is for Oracle or SQL Server... nothing for mysql.

I have approximately 15 tables with 75 fields that should be anonymized.

Has anybody found a recommended solution(s)?

Answer (score 8):

You can anonymize all entries in a MySQL table simply with

```
UPDATE users SET email = concat('user_', id, '@example.com');
```

i.e. by using an SQL Update with string expressions. The user with ID 1 gets the email user_1@example.com, the user with ID 10 gets user_10@example.com, etc.

Comment: Coolest answer I've seen all day

Comment: This affect to production DB ,that's not what I want , is there any way to mask only dumped sql?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from Gartner that Camouflage data masking supports mysql and has a free downloadable version.

Check out - http://www.datamasking.com/products/featured-product-downloads